Where can I find the derivation of the law of mass action for liquids?
I already asked this in chemistry and all they gave me was a link to the historical derivation. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68195/
But this derivation relies on the Maxwell-Botlzmann distribution. As far as I know, liquids have complicated equations of state and the Maxwell-Botlzmann distribution assumes the only energy of a molecule comes from its velocity.
I was also told that liquids have a well-defined Gibbs Free Energy.
So given than the energy of molecules in liquids also depends in the molecule to molecule interaction, where can I find a derivation of the law of mass action for liquids?
Or where can I find how the usage of the Maxwell-Botlzmann distribution and collision theory is justified, given liquids have very different behaviour to ideal gases?

Are you looking for chemical reactions of liquid v.s. liquid, or are you looking for chemical reactions that are happening in the aqueous setting?

That is one of the things I don't get. There is nothing magical about water except that it is a very polar liquid. So it is a very powerful polar solvent. I assume the law of mass reactions only applies with concentration coefficients to aqueous reactions? Because I am interested in the general case but if you have info on aqueous that is fine

The aqueous case is actually much easier. It turns out that in the dilute aqueous setting makes it such that each reactant behaves as if it is an ideal gas that ignores the water background, and so the law of mass action is most easily obtained as by directly copying the ideal gas results. You should consult a statistical mechanics textbook on this; it is quite important and so it is always labelled in the contents page in textbooks that cover it.
